# unresolved external symbol __imp__wcsstr

Tags: c++

I am getting the following linking error : `libOpenSSL.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wcsstr` while linking he openssl library to my project. But this looks like a generic error than a openssl error.

Anybody having any idea, i am missing to include any windows library?

Comment: Have you disabled linking to the CRT?

Comment: Ya actually i excluded the Msvct.lib, but now i found it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this error. Need to include `Msvcrt.lib` to resolve this error.

Comment: The only possible way you have to do this explicitly is when you #include not a single standard C or C++ header.  That's quite hard to do.  A wrong compile setting (C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime Library) is the more likely cause.  Getting them mixed can cause very hard to diagnose runtime problems.